# Displaying correctly formatted HTML code inside <input>

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently writing a "template generator" so that users can fill in a form and then HTML code is automatically filled in and they can copy paste the HTML code into another file and it's good to go.

In my generator there is the form, and then the HTML code to copy paste appears in full underneath the form so that users would have to select all of it. It's currently written like this:

```
<code>
   <pre>
      &lt!DOCTYPE html&gt
      &lthtml lang="en"&gt
      ...
      <span class="form-info-1>
      ...
      <span class="form-info-2>
      ...
      &lt/html&gt
   </pre>
</code>
```

so that it displays correctly with the tags.

Because the HTML code to copy paste is super long, right now I have to select and scroll down for quite a while to catch all of it to copy paste it.

What I want to do is insert the correctly formatted HTML code into an input box (or something similar) so users can just select all in the input box and copy paste it into another file. Right now I have not been able to do this as I can't manage to get rid of the < and > tags when putting them in an input.

I hope this is clear, any help is appreciated

Comment: Please share the relevant, minimal reproducible code.